# PDF easytable - may I insert table within cell?

Tags: java, pdf

All information in subject - may I insert table within cell using PDF library "easytable" ? And if "yes" - how could I do it ?

Thank you.

Comment: can you do some example

Answer (score 2):

> may I insert table within cell?

Well, yes you may.

I don't know your exact requirements and why this would be necessary since I guess that most probably you could already "mimic" tables within tables by just using row spanning and cell spanning, but to give you one example:

[image]

The code for this example can be found in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/vandeseer/bb86e12d01ca18b9306901ae2bf73cf9) with the basic idea of subtyping the abstract cell class and adding a custom drawer.